# How can I profile the tab completion of the :find command?

Tags: vim

I would love for `:find` to work from my homedir, but when I `:find foobar<TAB>` it simply does not come back for *ages* (well I haven't left it running for more than 1 min, but that's already unacceptable).

It must be getting lost somewhere in some directory. If I could get some feedback on exactly where it is getting lost I could add some `wildcardignore+=**/<dir name>` into my `.vimrc`.

Using the advice from [Thoughtbot here](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/profiling-vim), I tried:

```
:profile start vim_profile.log
:profile file *
:profile func *
:find foobar<TAB>
<Ctrl-C after a while>
:q
```

but I was not able to deduce anything from the `vim_profile.log`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm assuming you have `set path=**`, correct? How long does it take to execute a command such as `find ~ | wc -l` in the shell? The Vim command will take a comparable amount of time...

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/tpope/vim-apathy/blob/master/README.markdown#rationale) for an argument on why setting `'path'` to `**` is not really desirable or recommended. What you probably want instead is a fuzzy finder such as fzf.

Comment: The performance should be equivalent to the same use of `glob()`. And its code is complex. See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/vim_dev/SEPEM44lsl8/1jZoiksZFgAJ;context-place=forum/vim_dev If your file system has poor performances, the result could be much worse than `find` tool.

Comment: Yes @filbranden I have set `path+=**`. This was all inspired by [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XA2WjJbmmoM) on how to do plenty of stuff in Vim without using a plugin.

Comment: @Robert Yes I've seen the video. But unless you *really* can't use a plug-in for some reason, you should probably avoid using something like that.

Comment: @Robert much of vim’s builtin awesomeness relies on path. Use a plugin for fuzzy finding if you need one.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I am intrigued, do you have links to articles/videos on how one should take advantage of the 'path-based awesomeness'? Many thanks.

Comment: @Robert no videos i can think of immediately, but many language plugins (or even just default filetype plugins) set it and other options appropriately. Check out the link from filbranden; it gives a list of all the commands that use these features. I’m even working on a wiki-style plugin that leverages a lot of this functionality to keep the codebase very tiny. gf, find, [i, all use path. They enable very fast navigation.